# $lookup(Aggregation) using pymongo

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

The following are the two collections I have:

```py
db.try1.insert([
    {id: 123, product:"earphones", ref:"asdf"},
    {id: 321, product:"speaks", ref:"zxcv"}
])

db.try2.insert([
    {rf:"zxcv", Owner:"Jeff"},
    {rf:"asdf", Owner:"John"}
])
```

I used the following aggregate statement

```py
cursor_3=db.try1.aggregate([{
    "$lookup":{
        "from":"try2",
        "localField":"ref",
        "foreignField":"rf",
        "as":"rightstuff"
    }
}])
```

However I am not getting the desired output. The array rightstuff remains blank.
I am using Mongodb 3.2 and pymongo driver.

Fixed it.

Comment: Your query is fine.

Comment: Hi Spartan07 - if you fixed your problem, could you post it as an answer? That way, you can let other readers know how to solve similar problems; and it will also take your question off the unanswered list.

Answer (score 0):

If it is a pymongo code, you should to enclose in quotes the field's name like this:

```py
db.try1.insert([
    {'id': 123, 'product':"earphones", 'ref':"asdf"},
    {'id': 321, 'product':"speaks", 'ref':"zxcv"}
])

db.try2.insert([
    {'rf':"zxcv", 'Owner':"Jeff"},
    {'rf':"asdf", 'Owner':"John"}
])
```

Your code of aggregating query is correct.